# Python: Return Value and Return None

Tags: python

I can't figure out why the function returns the correct letter when I enter "N" or "n". The function is called but return "None" when I enter the incorrect letter.
The function should be keep looping until the correct letter is entered.

This is the output when I enter the correct letter.

```
(N)ew game
Your choice?: n
Your choice before returning the value to main: n
Your choice: n
```

This is the output when I enter the incorrect letter.

```
(N)ew game
Your choice?: j
Wrong input
(N)ew game
Your choice?: n
Your choice before returning the value to main: n
Your choice: None
```

Source code:

```
def auswahl():
    print("(N)ew game")

    choice = input("Your choice?: ")

    if choice == 'N' or choice == 'n':
        print("Your choice before returning the value to main:", choice)
        return choice
    else:
        print("Wrong input")
        auswahl()

#main
eingabe = auswahl()
print("Your choice:", eingabe)
```

Comment: Your `else` branch has no `return`

Comment: Note though that recursion is the wrong solution here anyway.

Comment: But if i put a return there, it gets back to main?! With recursion u mean that the function calls itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `auswahl()` you are just calling your function recursively, but do nothing with the value it produces.

It would have to be `return auswahl()`.

*However*, note that using recursion in functions that take user input [is considered harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23294659/3620003) because you can blow the stack if a user fails too many times. See the "Common Pitfalls" section of the answer I linked to.

**~edit~**

> But if i put a return there, it gets back to main?! With recursion you mean that the function calls itself?

Yes, recursion in this contexts refers to a function calling itself. `return auswahl()` does not immediately return from the function, it has to wait for the result another call to `auwahl` produces. Of course, in that other call the user could fail again, which would trigger another call, and so on ...

Comment: Thank you timgeb "return auswahl ()" works. I will read that link and try my luck with "try" and "except".

Comment: @KapitaenWurst no problem. The accepted answer in that other question is a complete guide how to write a good function that takes user input.